# YAML list in spring framework without springboot

Tags: java, spring, yaml

**NOTE**: NO SpringBoot. ONLY Spring Framework.

I see this works with `@ConfigurationProperties` in a springboot project. But I can't get it to work with `@Value` in a spring framework only project. It seems the `@Value` annotation cannot resolve the list correctly.

Here is a sample project: https://github.com/KiranMohan/spring-yaml.
For loading the yaml file, I used the `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`.
The code is tested in a junit `ExampleTest` class.
Output of

```
log.debug("myList: {}",example.getMyList());
```

is

> DEBUG [main] org.ktest.ExampleTest: myList: [${example.myList}]

Example yaml:

```yaml
example:
  enabled: true
  name: "org.ktest"
  myArray: >
    abc,
    def

  myList:
    - "ghi"
    - "jkl"
```

Example code:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:example.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class Example {

    @Value("${example.enabled}")
    private boolean enabled;
    @Value("${example.name}")
    private String name;
    @Value("${example.myArray}")
    private String[] myArray;
    @Value("${example.myList}")
    private List<String> myList;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `YamlPropertySourceFactory` uses [`YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.html) whose Javadoc states

> Lists are split as property keys with `[]` dereferencers, for example
> this YAML:
>
> ```
>  servers:
>  - dev.bar.com
>  - foo.bar.com.
> ```
>
> becomes properties like this:
>
> ```
> servers[0]=dev.bar.com  
> servers[1]=foo.bar.com
> ```

This is also mentioned in the Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.yaml.mapping-to-properties).

In other words, using these types, you can't feed that `example.myList` YAML element into a `List` through property resolution. You can only access individual elements like

```
@Value("${example.myList[0]}")
private String myListFirstElement;
```

The Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.yaml.mapping-to-properties) also mentions this. It suggests

> Properties that use the `[index]` notation can be bound to Java `List` or
> `Set` objects using Spring Boot’s `Binder` class.

You can try looking at how that class does it and reproduce it in your own code.